# Instantiate TypeScript LanguageService w/plugins via API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

How can I use the TypeScript compiler API to instantiate a languageService with language service plugins?  I thought that `createLanguageService` would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to load plugins.

Is this wrapped up in tsserver somewhere?  Ideally I want to run everything in-process.  Is there some sort of `ServerHost` I need to instantiate to give the `languageService` access to `require()` node_modules?

My motivation: I want to programmatically apply plugin quick-fixes to a codebase from a CLI tool I'm building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  `import * as ts from 'typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary';` (same import used when authoring plugins) and create a `new ts.server.ProjectService`.  Then open a source file via `projectService.openClientFile` which will cause the service to automatically pick up your tsconfig and create a new `ConfiguredProject` which you can retrieve via various methods.  Then `configuredProject.getLanguageService()`.

You have to set `serverHost.require` or else the service can't load plugins and they'll be skipped.  I copied TS's internal implementation from [src/server/server.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e53e56cf8212e45d0ebdd6affe462d161c7e0dc5/src/server/server.ts#L888-L895)

I'm leaving out a lot of messy details, but these are the steps.  Intellisense tells you everything else you need to do.

Comment: Really cool, thanks for this! Do you have a demo repo for this?

Comment: I'm currently trying (and failing) to run a Language Service Plugin from the command line over here: https://github.com/karlhorky/ts-language-service-plugin-formatting-cli